# Inkscape - Manipulating a plot

Tags: inkscape

Let's say I want to create a sine function with a circle around it using the function plotter in Inkscape. How could I turn it into one single object? (i.e. rather than have a sine function and a separate circle)

Actually, if I wanted to use that as, for instance, a logo, how would you guys recommend I do that?

Comment: I think the question is answerable and should be reopened.